# Prevent Microsoft Edge from adjusting numbers/units

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge, number-formatting, date-conversion

We provide a web app that shows numbers in an accounting format, e.g. 1.000,00 H or 1.000,00 S (where S and H mean debit / credit in German language).

In some instances, Microsoft Edge seems to detect time values based on S and H and alters the representation of the „units“:

1.000,00 H -> 1.000,00 hrs

1.000,00 S -> 1.000,00 sec

I couldn’t find any solution to either disable this on the client side (e.g. in Edge Browser settings) nor to prevent this kind of conversion by adding some meta data on the server side (preferred solution, since we would not need to instruct end users).

The issue is limited to Edge, other browsers are all displaying the values as expected.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

**SOLVED: It seems that some users have activated the built-in translation mode**

Comment: Try changing the Edge's Preferred Language to German.